# Aframe.io - is this aframe and how do you get panoramic camera easing as well as no-click rotation

Tags: background, three.js, panoramas, aframe

http://felixandpaul.com/

The background of their site is great. It reacts to mouse input without clicking to drag around, and works on mobile phone when accelerometer or phone is rotated like on facebook photosphere 360.

How would I get something like this as a background for a wordpress site. I want to use this same 360 background as I could a fullscreen slider background.

I'd pay for this functionality, but don't know where to find the help there.

I typically use Divi, Brooklyn, or Story when I'm building sites, so I'm not sure what would be my simplest solution?

Comment: There used to be a component to do this at https://github.com/alexrkass/aframe-no-click-look-controls/blob/master/index.js , but it's somewhat outdated. You can try adapting the code, or filing an issue. Just wrap it with `AFRAME.registerComponent` and try it out, until it gets updated. Or someone in Slack might volunteer to do it.

Comment: cool, I'm honestly not much of a true coder at all, I mean, I can hack my way around wordpress, but I'll look into your suggestion. How do I get to join the slack group?

Comment: https://aframevr-slack.herokuapp.com

Comment: The `universal-controls` component from [aframe-extras](https://github.com/donmccurdy/aframe-extras) does still support pointerlock, as well. At the moment, the other aframe pointerlock implementations seem to have fallen out of compatibility with A-Frame v0.3.0.